# Override type declaration in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hook-form, zod

I am trying to override the `UseFormSetValue` type in `react-use-hook-form`. I have an `override.d.ts` file which, to test, contains,

```
declare global {
  module "react-hook-form" {
    export * from "react-hook-form";

    export type UseFormSetValue<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = unknown;
  }
}
```

When importing the type, it is overridden correctly. However, when the type is used internally in `react-hook-form`, the override type declaration is not respected.

Any ideas how the type can be overridden internally? I would prefer not to have to use something like [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Comment: Try going to original definition of `UseFormSetValue` in `react-hook-form/UseFormSetValue` or whatever and override that instead

Comment: So you want to let the `react-hook-form` package use the types defined in `override.d.ts` in your project?

Comment: @Dimava This works, but since node_modules are not pushed to a repository, this would only work on my machine. ‘patch-package’ can apply some change to a package but seeing if that is avoidable.

Comment: @LinDu Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ReubenDrummond I mean `declare module 'react-hook-form/UseFormSetValue'` rather then 'react-hook-form'`

Comment: @Dimava Oh I see. I have tried overriding `react-hook-form/dist/types/form` (where `UseFormSetValue` is originally exported) and other paths too with no success.